# Linux mount NFS with specific user

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, mount

I was searching hours on the Internet, but for this specific problem I could not find any solution.

1: I have a Xubuntu Linux on my PC. I use it in average way: browse the Internet, watch videos, etc. And also it gives home for my PHPStorm app but no the project files. This is the  HOST. It has a host-only network: `192.168.56.1`

2: I have a VirtualBox Debian Linux (no GUI) system. This meant to be represent a development version of my real webserver. It has all the project files. This VM is on an external drive, so I can take it everywhere (e.g.: to the office). `192.168.56.101`. This is the GUEST.

3: on the HOST I use dnsmasq to force every *.dev domain to be redirected to the GUEST. So I can test my projects easily.

4: on the GUEST I exported the `/var/www` folder in the `/etc/exports`:

```
/var/www 192.168.56.1(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

**The problem:** I want to use the PHPStorm on the HOST to edit the files on the GUEST "locally". But I cannot mount the GUEST's `/var/www` folder into the HOST's `/home/gabor/Projects` folder with full permissions. I tried to use the following:

```
$> sudo mount 192.168.56.101:/var/www /home/gabor/Projects
```

This looks okay for the first time, but the folder is mounted with `nobody:nogoup` and I have no permissions to edit.

I want the `/home/gabor/Projects` has the owner `gabor:gabor` and everything I create in this folder must has the owner `www-data:www-data` on the Debian side. But for NFS mounting I cannot specify the user.

```
$> sudo mount -o umask=0022,gid=1000,uid=1000 192.168.56.101:/var/www /home/gabor/Projects
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

I also failed to `mount --bind` the `/var/www` with different user (should be `nobody:nogroup`) on the Debian, so that I could export that one...

How can I solve this problem? 
Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score -12, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution that exactly does what I want.

First, install the `sshfs`:

```
$> sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

Then mount the remote `/var/www`:

```
$> sshfs -o uid=33,gid=33 root@192.168.56.101:/var/www /home/gabor/Projects
```

And that is it!

```
$> ls -la /home/gabor | grep Projects
drwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  4096 Okt 14 21:10 Projects
```

Comment: Still, that's not a solution for the original problem which specifies NFS.

Comment: sshfs is not reliable, try to use NFS v4

Answer (score 3):

NFS v2 and v3 do not support uid/gid.

on Ubuntu `man nfs`

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer for posterity, as I ended up here with the same question.

Try this in /etc/export:

```
/var/www 192.168.56.1(rw,root_squash)
```

Then on the client, put this in /etc/fstab:

```
192.168.56.101:/var/www /home/gabor/Projects nfs defaults,user,noauto,relatime,rw 0 0
```

The `user` option will allow a non-root user to mount the volume.  Adjust other options as needed.

Then on the client again, become the user you want to mount the volume as, and then mount the volume you added to /etc/fstab:

```
$ id
uid=1000(gabor) gid=1000(gabor) groups=1000(gabor)
$ mount /home/gabor/Projects
$
```

Make sure that the `uid` and/or `gid` are the same on the server.  I'm not sure if the usernames can be different or not.  Also make sure that the directory being exported on the server is writable by the user or group.  See [this blog post](https://opensource.com/article/20/5/nfs-raspberry-pi) for additional info about setting up NFS in a similar manner.

**Caution**: This is an insecure configuration without authentication.  Use NFS v4 with Kerberos for strong authentication.

Comment: exporting with `rw,sync,root_squash` - mounting in fstab with `defaults,user,noauto,relatime` ... the ownership of the mount point on the client shows the same uid and gid as on the server, but I can write to it now with the user that mounts it. Note that I was not able to write to the directory after mounting before without matching uid and gid on server and client until I made these changes as suggested. Also note - even after these changes I cannot write to the directory AS ROOT if I mount it as another user - I have to mount as root to write with root.